# Basic example of system controllability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples, control-theory

Ok so I'm having a tough time understanding an example in my book, there is a great deal of hand-waving and I'm having a hard time following. I'd like to see the example worked out if possible, with some explanation.

$ i) $ Given the harmonic oscillator system ( $ \Sigma $ ), where

$ \dot{\bar{x}}_1 = x_2 $

$ \dot{x}_2 = -x_1 + u $

does there exist a control $ u $ that can transfer the system from $ \begin{bmatrix} x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ to the origin $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ in $ 2\pi $ units of time? If yes, find $ u $, otherwise explain why not.

$ ii) $ Does there exist a feedback control law

$ u = \begin{cases} u_1 \space \space \space  0 \leq t \leq 2\pi  \\ u_2 \space \space \space {2\pi/3} \leq t \leq 4\pi/3  \\ u_3 \space \space \space 4\pi/3 \leq t \leq 2\pi \end{cases} $

so that $ \Sigma $ can be steered from $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ to the state $ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $?

If yes, find $u_1, u_2, and \space  u_3 $, otherwise explain why not.

Comment: What theorems do you know for determining when a system is (exactly/null/etc.) controllable?

Comment: So far, we have learned the Gramian controllability matrix W_c. If it's rank is equal to n the system is controllable. W_c is positive definite for all t>0. We also learned about the PBH test.

Comment: Ok, so you can use $W_c$ to determine the controllability for i), right? For ii), what is the relationship between exact controllability and null controllability for systems of this form?

Comment: In theory I understand how to do that yes, but I'm having difficulty setting the problem up, also, the question asks to find $ u $ which I'm not 100% sure on how to do either! I'm obviously a novice so many things are not trivial or obvious to me, explanations are much appreciated. My prof. is a researcher and cares very little about his classes, and we don't have many people to ask for help sadly.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what book/reference you are using, and then I can try and put up a solution.

Comment: Also, for part ii), are the $u_i$'s supposed to be constant?

Comment: So, we're using Linear System Theory and Design by CT Chen, (not sure which edition, our prof. never uses the book as he thinks it's too slow). I believe this is Chpt. 6, example 6.5.

Comment: As for the $ u_i $ values, I'm not sure, I guess maybe they are since having a D with a constant value would make the problem easier(?)

Comment: I added a solution to the other parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First part of i)** Rewrite the system in terms of matrices:

$$
x' = Ax + Bu
$$

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right), B = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right).$$

Controllability tests:

**PBH** Form the matrix $(sI - A \,\,\, B)$ and check that it has rank $2$ for all $s$.

$$
(sI - A \,\,\, B) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} s & -1 & 0\\ 1 & s & 1\end{array}\right)
$$
Further, you only have to check the case $s = $eigenvalue, since $sI - A$ is invertible (i.e. of rank $2$) for any other $s$. In this case, the eigenvalues are $i,-i$. Can you convince yourself that $(sI - A \,\,\, B)$ is rank $2$?

**Gramian mx** We want to see if the Gramian matrix has full rank:
$$
W_c = \int_0^{2\pi} \exp(At)BB^T\exp(A^Tt)\,dt
$$

Next, find the fundamental solution $\exp(At)$ of this system

$$
\exp(At) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos(t) & \sin(t) \\ -\sin(t) & \cos(t)\end{array}\right)
$$

and observe $\exp(A^Tt) = \left(\exp(At)\right)^T$. Do all the matrix multiplication on the inside of the integral, and you should get

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\begin{array}{cc} \sin^2(t) & \sin(t)\cos(t) \\ \sin(t)\cos(t) & \cos^2(t) \end{array}\right) \,dt = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \pi & 0 \\ 0 & \pi\end{array}\right)
$$
which has full rank.

For the next part, I solved directly. The solution is
$$
x(t) = \exp(At)x^0 + \int_0^t \exp(-As)Bu(s)\,ds \\
=\left(\begin{array}{c} \cos(t) \\ -\sin(t)\end{array}\right) +  \int_0^{t} \left(\begin{array}{c} -\sin(s)u(s) \\ -\cos(s)u(s)\end{array}\right)\,ds
$$

To have $x(2\pi) = (0,0)^T$,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right) =  \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\begin{array}{c} \sin(s)u(s) \\ \cos(s)u(s)\end{array}\right)\,ds \quad \quad (*)
$$

A $u$ that works is $u(t) = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\sin(t)$ (this occurred to me b/c of orthogonality of sine and cosine; there are other choices, I'm sure).

For the final part, you need to see if there's a *piecewise constant* $u$ that works in $(*)$ above. So one equation the constants will have to satisfy is
$$
1 = u_1 \int_0^{2\pi/3}\sin(s)\,ds + u_2 \int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3} \sin(s)\,ds + u_3 \int_{4\pi/3}^{2\pi} \sin(s)\,ds
$$
and similarly
$$
0 = u_1 \int_0^{2\pi/3}\cos(s)\,ds + u_2 \int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3} \cos(s)\,ds + u_3 \int_{4\pi/3}^{2\pi} \cos(s)\,ds
$$

Evaluate the definite integrals, then solve for the coefficients.

Comment: Just sat down to take a look, so here's a question: would it be easier to use the observability/controllability duality to show that an alternate system $ \bar{\Sigma} $ is observable and therefore $ \Sigma $ would be controllable? When is the duality used?

Comment: I suppose you could, but some of the direct methods of verifying controllability were pretty fast (the PBH method; see also the 'controllability matrix'). I looked through your book, but couldn't find the exercise (diff. editions maybe?), so I can't say much about how they "want" you to solve this problem.